# Failed to Receive Data via sockets from Node.js to UWP app

Tags: node.js, sockets, networking, windows-store-apps, uwp

I have a problem i am try reading via sockets a string in uwp app from a node.js server with no success. I got an System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException and i dont know how to fix it. I manage to send with succes from the uwp client to the node server a string but i can't do the opposite. Here is my code what i am doing wrong?

This is my node.js Server Code

```
var _HOST = '192.168.1.67';
    var _PORT = 1337;
    var _address;

    var net = require('net');

    var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
        socket.on('connect', (e) => {
            console.log('client connected ' +
                socket.remoteAddress + ':' +
                socket.remotePort);
        });

        socket.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('clients says' + ': ' + data);

            var send = "hello client"
            console.log('Server says' + ': ' + send);
            socket.write(send + '\n');


        });

        socket.on('error', function(data) {
            console.log('client on error', data);

        });

        socket.on('close', (e) => {
            console.log('client disconnected');
            socket.end;
        });

    });
```

This is my UWP Code

```
  public async Task connect()
        {


            try
            {
                HostName hostName;

                hostName = new HostName(SocksParameters.Host);
                socket.Control.NoDelay = false;
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cts.CancelAfter(SampleConfiguration.timeout);

                // Connect to the server
                var connectAsync = socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, SocksParameters.Port);
                var connectTask = connectAsync.AsTask(cts.Token);
                await connectTask;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                await new MessageDialog("Make sure your Server is open and make sure you follow Instructions To connect localhost").ShowAsync();
                Application.Current.Exit();
            }

        }

public async Task<String> read()
        {
            DataReader reader;
            StringBuilder strBuilder;



            using (reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream))
            {

                try
                {
                    strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    reader.InputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.Partial;

                    reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                    reader.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

                    await reader.LoadAsync(256);
                    while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
                    {
                        strBuilder.Append(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));
                        await reader.LoadAsync(256);//System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Exception caught
                    }

                    reader.DetachStream();
                    return strBuilder.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {    
                    return (e.ToString());

                }
            }

        }
```

```
  Activated Event   Time    Duration    Thread
    Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.ni.dll ("The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
")  0.55s       [18700] <No Name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the code and I found if there is no more data can be read by the [`DataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208119) object `reader`, the code line `await reader.LoadAsync(256);` will always wait there until new messages send from server and `DataReader` can read it. In the code of yours if the size of coming data from server is less than 256, the second time you invoke the `LoadAsync` method may lead issues.

```
 await reader.LoadAsync(256);
 while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
 {
     strBuilder.Append(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));     
     await reader.LoadAsync(256);
      //System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Exception caught
 }
```

The workaround I provided here is to judge whether there is data left can be read. Updated code as follows:

```
 var loadsize = await reader.LoadAsync(256);
 while (loadsize >= 256)
 {
     loadsize = await reader.LoadAsync(256);
 }
 if (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
 {
     strBuilder.Append(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));
 }
```

In my opinion, it seems like you can use `StreamReader` which is also work for your scenario instead of `DataReader`since it is more simply to use. Code like follows:

```
Stream streamIn = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
return response;
```

More details about `StreamSocket` in uwp please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket).

Comment: your answer was totally helpful.For some unknown reasons i can't vote you up.Excellent answer!!!